Camunda 7 REST API for getting Jobs that are running currently
We use camunda community edition packaged in Wildfly.  We use rest api for starting workflows. All our workflows are async - so they executed through job executor of camunda.
We are not trying to get the current running workflows - meaning the jobs locked by the executor, i know we can get it through camunda DB using query.
SELECT    COUNT(*) FROM ACT_RU_JOB
WHERE (LOCK_OWNER_ IS NOT NULL AND LOCK_EXP_TIME_ >= NOW())
But i searched for REST API of camunda to achieve the same but couldn't find any. I went through https://docs.camunda.org/rest/camunda-bpm-platform/7.21/#tag/Job/  But no use.

can get the job count by this curl commend curl -u demo:demo "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/job?withLock=true" | findstr /C:"id" | find /C "id" 

given rest api is not having given parameter.  it returns all the jobs in the system
